# large switch statement implmentation and efficiency

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I have inherited some code that contains message processing code in a large number of places that is implemented as such:

```
switch(msgType)
{
    case msgType1:
        //....
        switch(msgSubType):
        {
            case msgType2:
            //....
        }
}
```

There are in the order of 10s of message types and 100s of message subtypes.  This code is frequently executed, and my question is in regards to its efficiency.  How efficient is code like this, especially with a large number of cases?  Are switch cases implemented as if-else statements?  Would some sort of hash or jump tables serve better? I am willing to sacrifice readability of the code for performance and am interested in any answers/recommendations.

Comment: I think this will eventually be optimized into jump tables under any decent modern compiler.

Comment: I agree with @H2CO3 - modern compilers should do it better than you. Just check assembler code or do benchmark what is really happening here, in order to be sure. I have made test a while ago on MSVC2010 - `switch` was O(1), I [tested 128 branches](http://imageshack.us/a/img856/6497/resultx64multipleseries.png).

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk great test! Which once again shows that the bloat of virtual functions is a debunked myth.

Comment: @rhalbersma when there is need for runtime dispatch then yes, virtual functions are not so bad. But, if you can avoid any runtime dispatch (not just `virtual`, but also `if`, `switch`, and so on) - you may gain much performance due to inlining. See `red` line on figure - it doesn't had any runtime disptach, and calculations were colapsed by compiler to simple expression, what was practically not possible for runtime dispatch.

Comment: Regardless of how well the compiler handles this code, it should be refactored for readability. Each `case` label should be followed by **simple** code, not another switch with hundreds of cases. Put that code in its own function, and call it as needed from the top-level switch statement.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk I had missed the red line as it drops so quickly to zero. But note that if the compiler can deduce which subclass is being called, there will be no virtual dispatch.

Comment: @rhalbersma Yes, especially with `PGO`&&`LTCG`. But anyway inlining of `virtual`s happens much more rarely than for plain calls. It is not rare in `C++` that 2-7 levels of nested `inline`s are collapsed into, literary, single `ASM` instruction.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk Agreed, but nevertheless, this code example just cries out for polymorphism. As it is, it's brittle and an unmaintainable mess. Sacrificing this much readability would really need an awful lot of performance as justification.

Comment: @PeteBecker, you hit the nail on the head: Just consider what a PC costs nowaday, and what a programmer hour costs. Do the math to see if "chasing the last 1% of performance" is worth it. And consider not only the programmer (re)writing said code today "for efficiency", but also the unending line of tortured souls trying to make head or tail of it, perhaps on some not even designed machine with totally different performance characteristics.